# Initialize size of vector<list<DATA> > and accesses

Tags: c++, list, vector, constructor, initialization

Hey I'm a little confusd about how the constructor initializes the size of the vector >.
This is my hpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std ; 

typedef struct { double successful[2] , unsuccessful[2] ; } Perform ;


template <class DATA>
class Table {
private :
    vector<list<DATA> > theList;
    typename list<DATA>::iterator itr;
    unsigned listSize;
    unsigned actualSize;
    unsigned probe;
...
```

and in my cpp

```
template <class DATA> Table<DATA>::Table(unsigned int size)
{
    listSize = size;
    actualSize = 0;
    probe = 0;
    theList(size); //Not sure how to make the vector of size "size"

}
```

and if I wanted to clear the lists in each vector location could I do a for loop and have the code be

```
theList[i].clear();
```

or would i have to do something different?

One last question is for inserting something into each of the lists in side the vectors, can I do

```
theList[i].push_back(data);
```

if not how do I do it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should ask only one question at a time. Create separate questions for the other things you're asking. That way, others will be able to find them and benefit from the answers

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you have discovered the difference between *initialization* and *assignment*.

Assignment occurs when you try to set an *existing* object to a new value; initialization is when an object is created and its constructor is called.

What you're doing in your constructor (which, for some reason, isn't shown in your header, making your code more confusing than it has to be) is assignment. By the time the constructor body executes, all members have been initialized.

To *initialize* a member, use the initializer list syntax:

```
template <class DATA> Table<DATA>::Table(unsigned int size)
  : listSize(size), actualSize(0), probe(0), theList(size)
{
}
```

This will call the constructor for each of the specified elements, with the specified arguments.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for the explanation as well. I understand what's going on now.

Answer (score 0):

To set initial size you can use initialer list,

```
template <class DATA> Table<DATA>::Table(unsigned int size)
 : theList(size) 
{
...
```

or by calling resize method inside:

```
theList.resize(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the code is right. This will create a vector with `size` elements, these elements will be default-constructed, which in ths case means they're empty lists. BUT you should place this initialization in the initialization list as follows (you should also do this for the other members btw).

```
template <class DATA> Table<DATA>::Table(unsigned int size) : theList(size)
{
    ...
}
```

This will prohibit the constructor from first calling the default constructor of your theList object (so it is a valid object).

The answer to your other questions is yes, but if you use C++11 you can probably save some tedious for-loops by using [for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and [lambdas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions), for example like this:

```
std::for_each(theList.begin(),theList.end(),[&data](std::list& l) { l.push_back(data)});
```